# bool accepts int literals, char literals, string literals - why?

Tags: c++

Programming: Practices and Principles - Bjarne Stroustrup

Drill in Ch 5 - Errors

He wants us to correct the code:

```
boo c = "fool"<s;
```

On correcting boo to bool, this is a comparison, so that's fine. c will be assigned either true or false. But if I edit it to

```
bool c = "fool";
```

It also evaluates to true. Then I tried "", 'd', 235, and they all evaluate to true. Shouldn't there be a type error? Narrowing conversion? Something? (I tried {} for checking narrowing conversions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), there is a conversion happening:

> Prvalues of integral, floating-point, unscoped enumeration, pointer, and pointer-to-member types can be converted to prvalues of type bool.
>
> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become false. All other values become true.

Comment: Thanks. The link to cppreference was too jargony for me to get. I tried to create a 'beginner' tag, but I need a lot of points for that. :(  I didn't get what you meant by prvalue. On searching, I was led to a pdf by Stroustrup on how they came up with the names. I got stuck on the basics of "has identity" and "can be moved". I've understood that prvalue is something that doesn't have identity but can be moved. But I don't know what that means in the first place. Can you explain in simpler terms?

Comment: @Andy356 welcome to programmers.SE! There's no need to denote your skill level in a tag. It's not desirable to have a lot of tags created all the time. That's why there's the reputation threshold to create new tags. If you feel like my answer answered your question, you can accept it. Otherwise, please clarify what's still unclear to you =)

Comment: Well, I ended my comment with the question I was unclear about...

Comment: @Andy356 my bad, was answering your comment before your edit. In simple terms: If some value of type `T1` is assigned to a variable of type `T2`, it will try to convert the `T1` value to `T2`. In very simple terms, everything that's not zero will be converted to `true`, otherwise `false`.

Comment: That part I understood from your answer. My question is why is that so? In Adam Horvath's answer below, he mentions the bool operator being used in the if brackets. But if we're using a bool variable now, why is there a need to accept anything as true? Why not throw up a type error?

Comment: @Andy356 Well, that's the way the language is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think the boolean operators are defined for these types to provide backwards compatibility with C code. In C it's legal to use integers in if-s

```
int i = 1;
if (i) {
    // Will step into, unless i is set to 0
}
```

Given these operators the "C-styled" code above compiles too. Also, in C++ :

```
if (/*Whatever you pass in, it's operator bool() is called here*/) {
    // And will step into if it's true
}
```

Read the chapter called "Operator Overloading".

Comment: Thanks. We learned in class when they taught us if statements, that anything you enter into the brackets is reduced to 1(true) or 0(false). But my question was why this happens to the bool variable also. Since now we're directly using the variable in the if brackets and not an expression, the backwards compatibility with C shouldn't apply, no?

Comment: @Andy356 it's essentially the same thing: think of the condition of the if statement to be a variable of type bool.

Comment: Okay, so the standard implemented bool variables exactly the way if conditions are, no changes?

Comment: There are no differences as neither (bool) casting nor bool() operator does know whether they're used in a boolean assignment or in if () condition.